# If the efficiency of a power supply is 60% when the input power is 25W, what power is delivered to the load

Tags: power-supply, efficiency

If the efficiency of a power supply is 60% when the input power is 25W, what power is delivered to the load? The formula for this problem is:

$$ Efficiency = \frac {Pout}{Pin} \times 100% $$ Where **Pout** is the Output power and **Pin** in the input power value.

The way this problem is worded I was thinking they wanted something other than just the output power value **Pout**. The answer in the book is 15W and I'm pretty sure they got that by multiplying 25W x 60% to get the **Pout** value. What i did, once I got the **Pout** value is: $$ Efficiency = \frac {15W}{25W} \times 100%$$ which equaled **60W**. I guess what confused me is that it stated "what power is delivered to the ***load***.", which made me they wanted the final value in Watts.

Comment: If the efficiency is 60% then the output is 60% of the input, so if you have 100W in then you get 60W out.

Comment: x watt, divided by y watt does not give a number in watts, but in fact a dimensionless number. Or fraction in your case, which multiplied by 100 becomes a percentage. All your answers are already in your question. The given answer is **the** answer and you proved that yourself by doing the calculation that re-created your 60%. The Pout you calculated with 25W x 0.6 = 15W is exactly what the question asks for and it is in watt, so there is absolutely no problem at all.

Comment: I think what trip me up was in the previous, very similar problem it stated, "What is the output power if...". There I just gave the Pout for the answer. Here it says "what power is delivered to the load", which now I know means they want the output power value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the point of the **x100** multiplier, in fact I don't think it is taught very well if it leaves out this crucial point . Whenever you are wanting to represent a decimal fraction as a percentage, you multiply by 100.

For example, 1/4 = 0.25. We know that one quarter is the same as 25%, not 0.25%, which is why this formula includes **x100**

Back to your original question:

60% = (Pout/25W) x 100

**60** / 100 = 0.6 = 15W/25W

Answer (score 0):

$$ Efficiency = \frac {15W}{25W} \times 100%$$

> which equaled **60W**.

No it doesn't. It equals **60%**.

You have just gone around in a complete circle.